# Что будет, если объявить объект родительского класса с конструктором дочернего класса?

Tags: java, полиморфизм

Что будет с программным кодом, если объявить объект родительского класса с конструктором дочернего класса?
Иначе говоря, какой конструктор вызовется: родительский или дочерний?

Comment: Э, э, э. Это как называется? Я уже ответил на первый вариант вопроса. Как теперь мой ответ будет выглядеть? :(

Comment: Извините, допустил в тексте опечатку(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос теперь выглядит примерно так: "Я вызываю дочерний конструктор. Какой конструктор вызовется: дочерний или родительский?"

Ответ: Вы вызываете дочерний конструктор. Вызовется дочерний конструктор. Надеюсь, что из него у Вас в коде вызывается родительский конструктор.

Comment: Да, все верно: вопрос именно такой